# Module Exporting result of async fn

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

I was using the standard node `mysql` package and abstracted away my db connections as such.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: host,
    user: user,
    password: password,
    database: database
});

module.exports = connection;
```

I want to use `promises` and am trying to use the wrappered `promise-mysql` package.

However, I'm unclear as to if I can still export my `connection` object.

```
const mysql = require('promise-mysql');

const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: host,
    user: user,
    password: password,
    database: database
});

module.exports = connection;
```

Do I have to wrap the `module.exports` in an IIFE or something?

Comment: You can only use await inside of an async function. There is probably no reason for you to be exporting a connection anyways. If you want to use the connection, just do so in your main script. Otherwise make a class that handles it all.

Comment: I want to abstract away the DB config params. These will be stored as Env Vars. What would you export, just an Object for the params, and instantiate a connection everytime it's needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the export be the Promise returned by the `createConnection` call. Also note that in ES6, you can use shorthand property names for conciseness and readability:

```
const mysql = require('promise-mysql');
module.exports = mysql.createConnection({
    host,
    user,
    password,
    database
});
```

Then users can use it by calling `.then` on the Promise, eg:

```
const connectionProm = require('script.js');
connectionProm.then((connection) => {
  // do stuff with connection
});
```

If you don't like having to call `.then` everywhere the connection is being used, an alternative would be to use dependency injection to pass the connection down as arguments, so that the connection's `.then` only has to exist in the script's entry point.

```
// index.js
connectionProm.then((connection) => {
  // do stuff with connection
  // pass it around as needed
});

// do NOT import or call connectionProm.then anywhere else
```

Comment: I'm using `async/await` instead of `.then`. But exporting the promise did the trick.
`const connection = await require('script')` works